# Can semisimple orbits be written $\exp(\mathfrak{g})\cdot x$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra and let $G$ be its adjoint group. If $x\in\mathfrak{g}^{rs}$ is a regular semisimple element, is its orbit
$$G\cdot x=\{\mathrm{Ad}_gx:g\in G\}$$
also equal to
$$\exp(\mathfrak{g})\cdot x=\{\mathrm{Ad}_{\exp(y)}x:y\in\mathfrak{g}\}?$$

Comment: Equivalently, do we have $G=EC_x$ where $E$ is the image of the exponential map, and $C_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$.

Comment: Note that the centralizer of a *regular* semisimple element is a maximal torus in $G$.   Is there a reason for limiting the question to regular elements or to the Lie group framework over $\mathbb{C}$?   (Naturally the notion of "exponential" would have to be broadened.)

Comment: Since $\exp(\mathfrak g)$ is not a group in general, I think, do you really want just $\exp(\mathfrak g)$, or the smallest set containing $x$ and closed under the adjoint action of $\exp(\mathfrak g)$?